# ng2 bootstrap issue during build Cannot find type definition file for 'core-js'

Tags: ng-bootstrap

ERROR in C:\projects\xxxx\node_modules@ng-bootstrap\ng-bootstrap\modal\modal-ref.d.ts
(1,1): error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'core-js'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in the @ng-bootstrap 1.0.0-alpha.12 release that was corrected in 1.0.0-alpha.13. More details are available in https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/1027

In short: 1.0.0-alpha.12 release is broken, use 1.0.0-alpha.13 release

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue after switching to the @ng-bootstrap 1.0.0-alpha.12.

After switching to alpha.13 the error disappeared.